# Change state of an existing object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

Hello I am working with react context and I have encountered a problem.

I have this component that contains all the logic :

```
import React , {useContext} from 'react';
import {TodoContext} from '../../contexts/todo-context';
import Todo from './Todo'; 
import './Todos.css';

export default function TodoList() {
    const [todos , setTodos] = useContext(TodoContext);

    const markComplete = (e) => {
       setTodos(prevState => [...prevState , {...e.target.value , done:true} ]); 
       console.log(todos);
    }


    return (
        <div className="TodoContainer">
            {todos.map(todo => (<Todo key={todo.id} todo={todo} markComplete={markComplete} /> ))}
        </div>
    )
}
```

I am passing down a markComplete function which will be used in the Todo component.

The Todo component :

import React from 'react'

```
export default function Todo({todo , markComplete}) {
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" value={todo} onChange={markComplete}></input>
            <li>{todo.title}</li>
            <div className="spacer"></div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Here I have a checkbox which onChange should trigger my markComplete function. This works, but the markComplete function doesnt change my state for some reason. Here's the function again :

```
const markComplete = (e) => {
   setTodos(prevState => [...prevState , {...e.target.value , done:true} ]); 
   console.log(todos);
}
```

It also generates an error saying that i should pass a key down (which i am already doing)

The state :

```
const [todo, setTodo] = useState([
    {
        title : 'Do the dishes', 
        done : false , 
        id: 123 
    },
    {
        title : 'wash car', 
        done : false , 
        id: 423 
    },
    {
        title : 'Buy pen', 
        done : false , 
        id: 323 
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you update your state is wrong.

Note that in your todo item, you did:

`<input type="checkbox" value={todo} onChange={markComplete}></input>`

While `todo` is itself an object, meaning that when doing this:

```
setTodos(prevState => [...prevState , {...e.target.value , done:true} ]);
```

You basically spreaded the object wrongly. In fact, the result of the next state update update:

```
0: {title: "Do the dishes", done: false, id: 123}
1: {title: "wash car", done: false, id: 423}
2: {title: "Buy pen", done: false, id: 323}
3: {0: "[", 1: "o", 2: "b", 3: "j", 4: "e", 5: "c", 6: "t", 7: " ", 8: "O", 9: "b", 10: "j", 11: "e", 12: "c", 13: "t", 14: "]", done: true}
```

This explains the `unique key` error you got.

One possible solution would be to use a wrapper to the change handler that passes the item id and the checked status:

```
function Todo({todo , markComplete}) {
    const handleChange = React.useCallback(e => {
        markComplete(todo.id, e.target.checked);
    }, [todo, markComplete]);

    return (
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" value={todo.id} onChange={handleChange}></input>
            <li>{todo.title}</li>
            <div className="spacer"></div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

markComplete:

```
const markComplete = (id, checked) => {
   setTodos(prevState => prevState.map(it => it.id === id ? ({ ...it, done: checked }) : it));
}
```

I would also recommend using `useCallback` in the above function.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vdzbj16a/